# Aliasing in continous-time signal

Tags: sampling, nyquist, aliasing

I have the following [signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5WA4.png) and it was plotted with a sampling frequency (Fs) of 5Khz and F0 was then varied for 0.5Khz, 2Khz, 3Khz, and 4.5Khz. I obtained aliasing when F0 = 2Khz and 3Khz only.

Correct me if I am wrong, however I know that the normalized frequency (f) = F0/Fs and I know that aliasing can be avoided if you work in the range -0.5<f<0.5. However when for instance using F0=2Khz I should obtain f = 2Khz/5Khz = 0.4 which should be in the range mentioned. However aliasing is still being observed. Why is this so? Am I forgetting something in the theory?

F0 = [0.5Khz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSdIX.png); [2Khz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsXZY.png); [3Khz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtoTV.png); [4.5Khz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdlT5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is aliasing at 3 kHz and 4.5 kHz.

The 2 kHz does not, but since 2 kHz and 3 kHz are equally far apart from the 2.5 kHz Nyquist frequency, they look similar.

Same with why 0.5 kHz and 4.5 kHz look similar.

Comment: I am still not understanding how visually you can say there isn't aliasing at 2Khz. How can I come to a conclusion that nyquist criteria is being obeyed when the plot says otherwise?

Comment: Maybe you are interpreting the plot wrong. Based on what can you say there is aliasing, while the theory and plot says there isn't?

Comment: Well because for 2Khz and 3Khz the signal was not recovered without loss. This was not the case for 0.5Khz and 4.5Khz. Then re. the theory when considering the range -0.5<f<0.5, with f being F0/Fs, to determine if the signal will be aliased or not, it would state that as you mentioned there is aliasing at 3Khz and 4.5Khz since f would be 0.6 and 0.9 respectively.

Comment: So visually, I would think that the signals F0 = 2Khz and 3Khz are aliased. But according to the theory there is aliasing only for 3Khz and 4.5Khz. This is why I am a bit confused.

Comment: The 2 kHz signal is fine. The 3 kHz signal is not, because it looks identical to 2 kHz signal, because 3 kHz is aliased, and you can't tell the difference between them. The 4.5 kHz signal is also not fine, because it looks identical to 0.5 kHz signal, and you can't tell the difference between.

Comment: Hmm I think I understood what you mean. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

From the Nyquist sampling theorem, the minimum required sampling rate to avoid aliasing is $2f_m$, where $f_m$ is the maximum frequency of the message signal.
Can you please add some plots for the question description to view the results.

Comment: I included the plots accordingly